# Redux constantly updating

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-thunk

I am building an app with React Native using expo and I implemented Redux. Now in my component I need to fetch some stuff from an API to fill a list. I decided to use the useEffect hook to accomplish that. Now in the dependency array of my useEffect hook I put my Redux state list. Like this:

```
const onFetchOrders = async (query: string, offset: number, limit?: number, filter?: {}) => {
  await props.fetchOrders('', 0);

}

useEffect(() => {
  setIsLoading(true);
  onFetchOrders('', 0);

  if (props.orders.length > 0) {
    setOrders(props.orders)
  } else {
    setIsLoading(true);
  }

}, [props.orders])
```

The orders are getting mapped to the props in another component:

```
const mapState = (state : RootState) => ({
    orders: state.orders.items,
    debtor: state.debtor.debtor,
    totalCount: state.orders.totalCount
})

const mapDispatch = (dispatch: any) => {
    return {
      fetchOrders: (query?: string, offset?: number, limit?: number, filters?: {}) => dispatch(tFetchOrders(query, offset, limit, filters)),
      fetchDebtor: (uuid: string) => dispatch(thunkFetchDebtor(uuid)),
      fetchCredentials: () => dispatch(thunkFetchCredentials()),
    };
  }

//const connector = connect(mapState, mapDispatch)(Root);
export const connector = connect(mapState, mapDispatch);

export type OrdersProps = ConnectedProps<typeof connector> & OrderStackNavProps<"Orders">;
```

Now if I start the app my useEffect hook constantly rerenders because there seems to be an update in the orders array.

Comment: Maybe `onFetchOrders` updates your orders array?

Comment: why do you use internal orders variable and props.orders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you wrote your `useEffect` hook it will run every time the `props.orders` change, because you passed that prop in the array as an optional argument. You can read more about how `useEffect` works in the ReactJS docs [here](https://en.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects).

If you want your `useEffect` hook to run only once when the component renders you should pass an empty array:

```
useEffect(() => {
  setIsLoading(true);
  onFetchOrders('', 0);
}, []);
```

Once you kicked off your fetch you can add the orders to the props in another `useEffect` hook:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (props.orders.length > 0) {
    setIsLoading(false);
    setOrders(props.orders)
  } else {
    setIsLoading(true);
  }

}, [props.orders])
```

Answer (score 0):

The useEffect runs everytime any prop changes in the component. To avoid this and still have orders in your useEffect array you can use [destructuring assignment syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```
const { orders } = props // where the magic happens

useEffect(() => {
  setIsLoading(true);
  onFetchOrders('', 0);

  if (orders.length > 0) {
    setOrders(orders)
  } else {
    setIsLoading(true);
  }

}, [orders])
```

This code will now only run whenever the orders prop  changes and not when any of the other props change.

Also, if forgot to mention, check out [useEffect infinite loop problem](https://medium.com/@infinitypaul/reactjs-useeffect-usecallback-simplified-91e69fb0e7a3). You can combine your useEffect hook with useCallback hook to avoid infinite loops.

Wrap the function that you want to pass into the useEffect hook with the useCallback hook. Then call the wrapped function in the useEffect hook. This will avoid an infinite loop in your useEffect.

```
const loadCustomers = useCallback(async (query: string, offset: number, limit?: number, filter?: {}) => {
    await props.fetchOrders('', 0);
    ...
}
```